# Questions about Robots.txt regarding asterisk and forward slash

Tags: robots.txt, web-crawler

I have few questions regarding robots.txt

1. If I have following line in robots.txt

   Disallow: /catalog/category/view/id/6

   will this block the url `http://example.com/catalog/category/view/id/61` as well?
2. If I have

   Disallow: /*education

   will this block the url `http://example.com/some/uri/education` as well as `http://example.com/some/uri/education/another/uri`
3. what makes the difference whether I have `/` at the end of each rule?
4. Is `*` necessary in `Disallow: /disallowme*` if I want to disallow all url that starts with `http://example.com/disallowme`

Answer (score 0):

(Q1)

```
Disallow: /catalog/category/view/id/6
```

will block any URL whose path starts with `/catalog/category/view/id/6`. So yes, it will also block `http://example.com/catalog/category/view/id/61`.

(Q3) A slash is just another character, nothing special about it.

(Q2, Q4) The `*` character has no special meaning in the original robots.txt specification, it’s just another character, like `/` and `a`. Some parsers ([for example, Google’s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22156788/1591669)) use `*` for pattern matching. You’d have to check their documentation about it (each parser might implement this differently, as there is no specification about it).

So parsers that follow the original specification will [*not*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23046581/1591669) block `http://example.com/disallowme` when following `Disallow: /disallowme*`. They would block, for example: `http://example.com/disallowme*foo`. As explained above, whatever you specify in `Disallow` is always an URL path **prefix**.